# $(document.activeElement) is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, document

I need to get the current active element on my web page I used

```
   $(document.activeElement)[0].id
```

This is working fine in Internet Explorer, but in Firefox it always return empty string `""`

Please tell me how can I get active element's `id` in Firefox?

Here is a simple scenario

I have 2 div with ID div1 and div2 respectively, now when user click on them I should get it's ID

Here is my markup

http://pastebin.com/BCW8ECMx

Comment: That would be the way, though the `$()` and `[0]` aren't really necessary for it. If it's returning `""`, then the `activeElement` likely doesn't have an `id` set on it. Is the element with focus the one you're expecting when that line is evaluated? Can you elaborate and possibly include the relevant markup? Perhaps a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) to demonstrate?

Comment: Please debug your application using `console.log(document.activeElement)` to see if it's the element you're expecting. This is almost always the first step in resolving such issues.

Comment: be aware that document.activeElement isn't always available, when there is no selection, the active element is the page's <body> or null. On a mac any other than text input elements tend not to get focus, this could cause errors because your script expects a non empty array.

Comment: I have updated the question with markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the event's `target`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).click(function (e) {
      alert(e.target.id);
   });
});
```

JSFiddle example found [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/ZY8vA/)

Comment: Thank you! this worked as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the code. But, the fact that, `div` **cannot** be active.

In fact, elements, which a user cannot interact, cannot be active.

For such elements, the id of the `<body>` will be returned.

Comment: [Documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)